# Renderização HTML5 com Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, razor

Segundo o W3Schools um input não tem fechamento de tag ex

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
```

fonte:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

No meu projeto ASP.NET MVC tenho o seguinte comando

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Erro, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

O resultado da renderização é

```
<input class="form-control" id="Erro" name="Erro" type="text" value="" />
```

O resultado não deveria ser o abaixo?

```
<input class="form-control" id="Erro" name="Erro" type="text" value="">
```

Tem alguma configuração a ser feita no ASP.NET, atualização, qualquer coisa para renderizar de acordo com HTML5?

Comment: Olho, pelo que já li até agora de HTML5 algumas tags não tem mais fechamento `/> ` obrigatório , mas  ainda pode ser usado o fechamento normalmente,  até pelo fato de dar suporte para versões anteriores .

Answer (score 5):

[Segundo o próprio W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp):

> In HTML, the `<input>` tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML, the `<input>` tag must be properly closed, like this `<input />`.

O HTML5 segue mais o padrão XHTML que HTML (4). Ou seja, está correto.